# Evaluating a complicated integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a function `Gamma`, but the output returns the input. I have the following code:

```
valuesfs = {r -> 50*10^-6, c -> 3*10^8*10^-15, Δt -> 55,
    m -> 9.11*10^-31, ϵ -> 8.85*10^-12*10^30, ϵip ->
     5.2*1.602*10^-19, 
   e -> 1.602*10^-19, λ -> 1300*10^-9, ℏ -> 
    1.054*10^-34*10^15, Γ0 -> 5, t0 -> 100, n -> 0.48, 
   Ip -> 5*10^17*10^-15};(*list of constants*)

E0 = Sqrt[(2 Ip)/(c*n*ϵ)] //. valuesfs;
Eenv[t_] = E0*E^-((t - t0)/(0.5*Δt))^2 //. valuesfs;
Ef[t_] = Cos[ω*t] //. valuesfs;
El[t_] = Eenv[t]*Ef[t];

Eexp = 1/(ℏ e) Sqrt[2 m] ϵip^(3/2) //. valuesfs;
El[t0] //. valuesfs;
(Eexp/Eenv[t0])^-1 //. valuesfs;

Γ[t_] = Exp[Eexp/Eenv[t]] Γ0 //. valuesfs
Ne = Integrate[Γ[tp], {tp, 0, 200}]
```

I want to know what value of `Ne` becomes when `Gamma` is integrated, but the output of `Ne` equals the unevaluated input. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `NIntegrate`evaluates `4.964292696444819*10^521122`. If this magnitude is expected try to `Rationalize`the integrand!

Comment: Note that the value of the integral from `tp = 0` to `tp = 199.999` is negligible compared to  the integral from `tp = 199.999` to`tp = 200`, at machine precision. (The ratio is less than `10^-16`.)

Answer (score 2):

Use exact values ([`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)) for the constants so that arbitrary precision can be used in the integration.

```
valuesfs = {r -> 50*10^-6, c -> 3*10^8*10^-15, Δt -> 55, 
    m -> 9.11*10^-31, ϵ -> 8.85*10^-12*10^30, ϵip -> 
     5.2*1.602*10^-19, 
    e -> 1.602*10^-19, λ -> 1300*10^-9, ℏ -> 
     1.054*10^-34*10^15, Γ0 -> 5, t0 -> 100, n -> 0.48, 
    Ip -> 5*10^17*10^-15} //
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;
(*list of constants*)

E0 = Sqrt[(2 Ip)/(c*n*ϵ)] //. valuesfs;
Eenv[t_] = E0*E^-((t - t0)/(Δt/2))^2 //. valuesfs;
Ef[t_] = Cos[ω*t] //. valuesfs;
El[t_] = Eenv[t]*Ef[t];
Eexp = 1/(ℏ e) Sqrt[2 m] ϵip^(3/2) //. valuesfs;
Γ[t_] = Exp[Eexp/Eenv[t]] Γ0 //. valuesfs;
```

Specify a `WorkingPrecision` and do not use the default integration method for `NIntegrate`

```
Ne = NIntegrate[Γ[tp], {tp, 0, 200},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15,
  Method -> "DoubleExponential"]

(* 9.92858538230830*10^521122 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
// N
```

to force numeric evaluation.

```
Ne = Integrate[Γ[tp], {tp, 0, 200}] // N
```

Comment: Much neater to use `NIntegrate` then, no?

Comment: i think so it's the same, but sometimes i just use //N to force evaluation to numeric value in any solution